# Google Tango Unity Examples not working

Tags: google-project-tango

I've tried the [codelab](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-motion-tracking) and followed the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMKMuYA_FcM) and and just can't make it work. In both cases the app loads, but (a) no motion tracking permission is requested and (b) the device motion does not control the camera.

These labs are super simple and don't contain any code, so I am fairly confident I do not have an error.

Unity v5.3.1f1 Personal
Unity Tango SDK FurudUnity5

Comment: when you said "no motion tracking permission", you mean it didn't pop up the permission scene. or in log, it showed fail, cause not motiontracking  permission? please update your TangoCore the latest version. and try again.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are running these code lab on a Tango device right? Also, double check if you have checked the correct checkboxes on TangoApplication prefab..

Comment: Yes definitely running on Tango device. Have latest Tango Core. Other Tango apps work on the device. Can get the device to ask for Area Learning permission if I add it, but not the Motion permission. I just dumped the code I am running [here](https://github.com/agawley/tangocodelab)

Comment: @AlexGawley, you shouldn't need motion tracking permission anymore. The permission check for motion tracking has been removed, I wonder if you are using an old SDK package. I will take a look of the project shortly.